# Toggle Between Two States in Javascript (and reveal hidden text)

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I'd like to toggle between two different states depending on if the user has clicked a link (which also makes a hidden text visible). Unfortunately, it's not working.

Any ideas to my code below?

````
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
   }

function swapStatus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("impctistmehr");
  if (x.innerHTML === "MEHR") {
    x.innerHTML = "Weniger";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "MEHR";
  }
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('impctist');" onclick="mswapStatus();" style="font-size:14px" class="impctistmehr"><strong>MEHR</strong></a>```
````

Comment: don't use innerHTML for your condition.

Comment: Also, your anchor does not have an `id`; it only has a `class` of `impctistmehr`. Use `document.querySelector(".impctistmehr")`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't trigger two functions by using the `javascript:` scheme in the `href` attribute. Instead, just call both functions in a third function attached to the `click` event listener.

Comment: Here's the code based on your input...still not working. Any ideas? `<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
   }

function swapStatus() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".impctistmehr")
  if (x === "MEHR") {
    x = "Weniger";
  } else {
    x = "MEHR";
  }
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('impctist');" onclick="swapStatus();" style="font-size:14px" class="impctistmehr"><strong>MEHR</strong></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Here you're using the method getElementById to get an element based on class.

You can either use document.querySelector('.classname') to get via class or give the element the id 'impctistmehr'.

Also there's a typo in method calling swapstatus.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo: `onclick="mswapStatus();"`, try `onclick="swapStatus();"`.